# Singleton reference for XHR upload function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, xmlhttprequest

Why does the first case not work? It is a reference to exactly the same function, only in singleton format.

Case 1..

```
var n = {
    doThis: function(e){
        console.log('hello world');
    }
};

xhr.upload.onprogress = n.doThis(e);
```

Case 2..

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        console.log('hello world');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you're calling the `doThis` function, you have to assign it to the progress property, e.g.

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = n.doThis;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = n.doThis
```

What you're doing is calling `n.doThis(e)` and storing the results into `xhr.upload.onprogress`.

Comment: Thanks, thought i had to pass on the event (e)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you call the function and assign the return value to the `onprogress` property.

You want to assign the function itself:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = n.doThis;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are creating a function object and assigning it to a variable onprogress.  For case 1, you are creating a named function (remember, the name is immaterial here, just a reference to the function object created), and for the second case, still a named function except here, the function name is a property on the object xhr.upload.

Now back to why case 1 does not work.  As others have mentioned, when you do `xhr.upload.onprogress = n.doThis(e);`, you are invoking the function and onprogress now points to the result of the function invocation.  However, omitting the invocation, removing `(e)` essentially makes onprogress a reference to the previously-created function object.

Hope that helps.